# Windows 7 fails to read recorded DVDs, says I "need to format the disk"

Tags: windows-7, dvd

I have a Pioneer DVR 215D. I've had various issues with it in the past - or rather, with its drivers, since it seems to work fine with Linux. Anyway, these days, with Windows 7, the OS refuses to any DVD disks I put in it (factory-pressed or home-recorded). With home-recorded disks, and I get a:

> You need to format the disc before you can use it

message, followed by a message regarding the failure to read the disk. With factory-pressed ones, I just get a:

> Please insert a disk into the DVD-RW drive

message.

The DVDs are fine (verified elsewhere). What can I do?

Notes:

- Microsoft's [FixIt Tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/mats/cd_dvd_drive_problems) for this problem doesn't find anything wrong, sends me to search online.

Comment: Does it have problems with factory-made DVD discs or only with the writable ones? What happens if you insert a blank recordable disk?

Comment: @Wayfarer: See edit.

Comment: When you say "it seems to work fine with Linux. Anyway, these days, with Windows 7" do you mean it *still* works with Linux, or that that was in the past? Have you tried connecting it to a different SATA port in the computer?

Comment: Looks like a hardware failure to me. Could you try the drive on a different computer? Also, browse to the [Pioneer DVR-215D product page](http://www.pioneerelectronics.com/PUSA/Professional/Computer-Drives/DVR-215D), check the drive properties with the DeviceInfo tool and apply the firmware upgrade if the one it has it's older than the 1.22 version. Next step would be to open the drive and try to clean the lenses.